# remove character from desire start to end in php

Tags: php, regex, string

Is there way to remove this character

This is my string  `$event = "Events:Boxing Fight no. 255 Odds:1-8 Side:Draw"`

I want to remove this `Fight no. 255 Odds:1-8 Side:Draw`

but my problem is the no. `255` is dynamic, it can be change on any number, and also the `Boxing` so how can i remove character start from `Fight no.` to end

i tried substr but the problem is that `Events:Boxing` is dynamic , the Boxing can change

Thank you

Comment: What are the rules here? You could split by the first space and use the first part only. _If_ there are no spaces in the event name, like `Event:Square Dance`. If `Fight no.` always exists in the string find its position inside the string and remove the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex but have to learn a lot, I want to show you a more simple way:

Split your string into 2 parts: the part you want to skip and the rest.

```
$array = explode(' Fight ', $event);
$skip = $array[0];
```

The rest will be:

```
$rest = $array[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The [strstr function](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php) makes it a little bit shorter.

```
$part1 = strstr($event,"Fight no",true);
```

Comment: Brilliant, you beated me haha

Comment: You  Huy Trịnh  got me the inspiration it not to do with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with regex:

```
$event = preg_replace("/(?i)Fight no.*/", '',$event)
```

here,

'i' flag(With this flag the search is case-insensitive)

'.'(Matches anysingle character except a new line)

'* '(Matches any zero (0) or more characters) Fight no.*(Matches fight no to end of the sentence)

NB: sometimes regex is useful for dynamic match. Ex: here Fight no is case sensitive. if your text is changed with 'fight No' or 'Fight No' you have to write code in multiple times with other functions but with regex function using 'i' flag you can do it with a single
code.